# class call in square brackets in django, python

Tags: python, django, class

This snippet is from djangoproject.com tutorial. Can someone explain why this line is written in this way:

```
inlines =[ChoiceInline]
```

instead of

```
inlines = ChoiceInline
```

why there are square brackets around class ChoiceInline?

---

```
from django.contrib import admin
from naslovnica.models import Poll
from naslovnica.models import Choice

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
    (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
    ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines =[ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date', 'was_published_recently')
    search_fields = ['question']
    list_filter = ['pub_date']

admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Comment: Thank you all for answers. I choosed Lafad just because im new to programming and his answer was easiest for me to undersood. But all of answers are meaningfull for me now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inlines =[ChoiceInline]` this is not a calling of class. This will create new list which has `class` as first element.

Class calling will be done as `ChoiceInline()`.

Comment: can you describe more what inlines is and can there be more elements and also which kind? other elements are classes too?

Comment: `inline` is list and `ChoiceInline` is `class`. When you declare `inlines =[ChoiceInline]` it will define `inline` as `list` with one element. `inline[0]` will return you `ChiceInline` class, not `ChoiceInline` object.

Answer (score 4):

It's not a "class call". It's simply a list. You can have multiple inlines, hence the plural, and you need to have them inside a list or a tuple.

Comment: what is exactly inline? why it is written in class? do you know more about that? where i can read more about it?

Comment: But that is explained in exactly [the place where you got that code from](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/#adding-related-objects).

Comment: You could also have `inlines =(ChoiceInline,)`. Where `(ChoiceInline,)` is a tuple of only one element.

Comment: @Daniel I am trying to figure out about what is inlines part of and i couldnt do that from that tutorial. so i asked for help here.

Answer (score 1):

Inlines are a list of InlineModelAdmin, TabularInline or StackedInline.
This allows you to add "inline" forms for related models.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects

> The admin interface has the ability to edit models on the same page as a parent model. These are called inlines.

Answer (score 1):

It receives a list or a tuple of Classes, because Django uses it as a special `ModelAdmin` class, like an extension to `BaseModelAdmin`.

Internally, Django will instance this classes, as you can see here:

```
def get_inline_instances(self, request, obj=None):
    inline_instances = []
    for inline_class in self.inlines:
        inline = inline_class(self.model, self.admin_site)
        if request:
            if not (inline.has_add_permission(request) or
                    inline.has_change_permission(request, obj) or
                    inline.has_delete_permission(request, obj)):
                continue
            if not inline.has_add_permission(request):
                inline.max_num = 0
        inline_instances.append(inline)

    return inline_instances
```

For a better understand I suggest you to see the options file in `django.contrib.admin` : https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/options.py